# Android: Webview and Activity

Tags: android, webview

I have hosted a web project in my system.I need to run the html content in Android application using WebView. I did that.My requirement is I need to get the content of the html page or Javascript inside it, in my activity.I sit possible.Please help me.

My html page contains one checkbox and some content inside

. I also have Save button. When I click the Save button I should get the content of the hidden fields inside the html page in My Activity .IS that possible. pls help me.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm having trouble understand you.. could you show some code to make things easier? perhaps this will help... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html

Comment: I have a webpage in my local machine.Also some hidden field for some data in that html. I loaded that url inside the webview. There is another button in the Activity other than webview. When I click the button I need the contents of that hidden field inside my activity.Is that possible.

Comment: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions

Comment: So you have a TextView or EditText that is behind the WebView?  And you need to get the data from the hidden view?

Comment: No I havent any TextView or EditText. My question is is it possible to get the content of webpage displayed in the webview, in my activity.ie content in the <input type="hidden" name="myName"> something like that

Comment: I want to know whether it is possible.That is why I asked this question

Comment: please help.I need to go whether it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the problem resolved.. In my activity I added a JavaScript interface with a javascript function named saved() in it.In my html page I added a javascript function named clicked().In this function I collected all the values as a String and passed to the saved().
The saved() function is in my activity and so I could use the values in my Activity.

```
In Oncreate()
{
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScript(),"demo");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}

final class DemoJavaScript {

        DemoJavaScript() {
        }

       // This is the javascript function
        public void saved(String values) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

// my html page

<script language="JavaScript">
          var values; 
                function clicked()
                {
               values="";
                values=document.getElementById('myvalue');
                  window.demo.saved(values);

                }
        </script>

<body>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" id="myvalue" value="reebok"/>





<br/>
<table>
<tr><td width="100" align=right><input type="button" name="save" value="Save" onClick="clicked()"/></td><td><input type="button" name="cancel" align=center value="Cancel"/></td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```